# What lock, if any, does 'CREATE TRIGGER' use in PostgreSQL 9.4.2

Tags: postgresql, triggers, postgresql-9.4

according to [postgres-xl](http://files.postgres-xl.org/documentation/explicit-locking.html), `CREATE TRIGGER` uses the `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE` lock, but according to the [official Postgres docs](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/explicit-locking.html) for `SHARE ROW EXCLUSIVE`:

> This lock mode is not automatically acquired by any PostgreSQL
>   command.

Comment: You're comparing Postgres-XL with the main PostgreSQL documentation. Two different products, albeit with a shared history. Postgres-XL has *lots* of changes from stock PostgreSQL. `CREATE TRIGGER` should be listed in the Pg docs and isn't, though, and that's an oversight.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You're comparing Postgres-XL with the main PostgreSQL documentation. Two different products, albeit with a shared history. Postgres-XL has *lots* of changes from stock PostgreSQL.

`CREATE TRIGGER` should be listed in the Pg docs and isn't, though, and that's an oversight.

A quick look at the source code shows that `CREATE TRIGGER` takes a `ShareRowExclusiveLock`, so in this case XL's documentation matches PostgreSQL's behaviour.

You could check this yourself without looking at the sources by doing something like this:

```
CREATE TABLE test();

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION dummy_tg() RETURNS TRIGGER
LANGUAGE plpgsql AS $$ BEGIN END; $$;

BEGIN;

CREATE TRIGGER blah BEFORE INSERT ON test FOR EACH ROW EXECUTE PROCEDURE dummy_tg();

\x

SELECT * FROM pg_locks 
WHERE pid = pg_backend_pid() 
AND relation = 'test'::regclass;

ROLLBACK;
```

... which shows that I was wrong about my reading of the sources, because:

```
locktype | relation
mode     | AccessExclusiveLock
```

it took an AccessExclusiveLock.

Comment: Going to comment here: I tried this with postgres 11.2 and it generates a ShareRowExclusiveLock for me, in all runs of this code.

Comment: @KdgDev There have been significant reductions of the lock level requirements for a number of utility statements in PostgreSQL since this was written 5 years ago.