# PostgreSQL BEFORE INSERT trigger locking behavior in a concurrent environment

Tags: postgresql, concurrency, triggers, locking

I have a general function that can manipulate the sequence of any table (why is irrelevant to my question). It reads the current value, works out the new value, sets it, and returns its calculation, which is what's inserted. This is obviously a multi-step process.

I call it from a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger on tables where I need it.

All I need to know is am I guaranteed that the function will be called by only one caller at a time in a multi-user environment?

Specifically, does the `BEFORE INSERT` trigger have to complete before it is called again by another caller?

Logically, I would assume yes, but one never knows what may be going on under the hood.

If the answer is no, what minimal locking would I need on the function to guarantee I can read and write the sequence in a "thread-safe" manner?

I'm using PG 10.

**EDIT**

Here is the function **updated with a lock**:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uts_set()                                     
RETURNS TRIGGER AS                                      
$$                                      
DECLARE                                     
  sv        int8;                               
  seq       text := format('%I.%I_uts_seq', tg_table_schema, tg_table_name);                                
BEGIN
  EXECUTE   format('LOCK TABLE %I IN ROW EXCLUSIVE MODE;', tg_table_name);
  EXECUTE   'SELECT last_value+1 FROM ' || seq INTO sv; -- currval(seq) isn't useable           
  PERFORM   setval(seq, GREATEST(sv, (EXTRACT(epoch FROM localtimestamp) * 1000000)::int8), false);                             
  RETURN    NULL;
END;                                        
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

However, a `SELECT` already acquires `ROW EXCLUSIVE`, so this statement may be redundant and a stronger lock may be needed. Or, conversely, it may mean no lock is needed.

**UPDATE**

If I am reading [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33902679/what-lock-if-any-does-create-trigger-use-in-postgresql-9-4-2) correctly, my original version without the LOCK should work since the trigger acquires the same lock my updated function is redundantly taking.

Comment: Are you sure that's a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger? You're returning NULL instead of NEW... there are others problems with the trigger definition too, but before anything, why do you need the greatest number between last value of sequence and current epoch * 1000000?

Comment: I am not 100% sure that `last_value` will work reliably - not even without concurrency.

Comment: It works perfectly with one caller. Well tested.

Comment: @michel.milezzi Thanks for correcting the NULL error. The function returns the current timestamp, but guarantees it is unique by using the sequence. So, for example, if one is inserting a thousand records, they will start with the current timestamp and increment by 1 each.

Comment: It should return NULL because this is a STATEMENT trigger.

Comment: @IamIC Ok, edited my answer for posterity. Regards!

Comment: Thank you. I eventually figured out how to do this correctly. I ran some brute force tests and proved your answer is correct. By calling an initially disregarded nextval() , I was able to convert the function to one op line, which runs atomically. I brute force tested it and there were zero errors of any type (deadlocks, duplicate keys, and gaps in the sequence, all of which occurred with the function as shown above).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***All I need to know is am I guaranteed that the function will be called by only one caller at a time in a multi-user environment?***

No. Not related to calling functions itself, but you can achieve this behaviour with [SERIALIZABLE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/transaction-iso.html#XACT-SERIALIZABLE) transaction isolation level:

> This level emulates serial transaction execution for all committed
>   transactions; as if transactions had been executed one after another,
>   serially, rather than concurrently

But this approach would introduce several tradeoffs, such preparing your application to retry transactions with serialization failure.

Maybe a missed something, but I really believe that you just need `NEXTVAL`, something like below:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION public.uts_set()                                     
RETURNS TRIGGER AS                                      
$$                                      
DECLARE                                     
  sv        int8;      
  -- First, use %I wildcard for identifiers instead of %s
  seq       text := format('%I.%I', tg_table_schema, tg_table_name || '_uts_seq');                                
BEGIN              
  -- Second, you couldn't call CURRVAL on a session 
  -- that you didn't issued NEXTVAL before
  sv := NEXTVAL(seq);                         

  -- Do your logic here...

  -- Result is ignored since this is an STATEMENT trigger   
  RETURN    NULL;                               
END;                                        
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Remember that `CURRVAL` acts on session **local** scope and `NEXTVAL` on **global** scope, so you have a reliable thread-safe mechanism in hands.

Comment: I found that I couldn't use NEXTVAL because it isn't initialized on a new table. Therefore, there is no way to ever insert a record because the first insert fails.

Comment: Since this is a trigger, this is the code, so I'd put the `SET ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE` as the first line, right?

Comment: Not so simple, it'll fail if your session already done a operation... it's safer to start entire transaction as serializable: `BEGIN TRANSACTION ISOLATION LEVEL SERIALIZABLE`.

Comment: I understand. I'm trying to achieve a solution where I can achieve this special "unique timestamp" goal without worrying about remembering to wrap each caller in that isolation level. I want the solution to be transparent to callers. Is this possible?

Comment: Surely there is an isoloation that can allow only one caller of the entire function at a time? Or some means of achieving this?

Comment: `SERIALIZABLE` It's not related to calling functions, but to read/write on database objects...

Comment: But, what do you mean with "I found that I couldn't use NEXTVAL because it isn't initialized on a new table."? What's "isn't initialized"? If sequence exists you can call nextval: `CREATE SEQUENCE test_sequence;
SELECT NEXTVAL('test_sequence');`

Comment: I meant to say I can't call currval initially, so I can't calculate the nextval.

Answer (score 0):

The sequence itself handles thread safety with concurrent sessions.  So it real comes down to the code that is interacting with the sequence.  The following code is thread safe:

```
SELECT nextval('myseq');
```

If the sequence is doing much fancier things like `setval` and `currval`, I would be more worried about that being done in a high transaction/multi-user environment.  Even so, the sequence itself should be locked from other queries while the sequence is being manipulated.

Comment: Unfortunately, the code is more fancy, so I can't rely on the sequence's thread safety.

Comment: Could you provide some of that code in your question?